# Dealing with returns of different types of methods in oop

Tags: python-3.x, api, oop, methods

I'm working with The Guardian Python API, through `TheGuardian.search_content()` and `TheGuardian.data_to_csv()` methods. The first one returns a dictionary, called `json_content`. The second one, iterate over json_content and write its content on a CSV file. My question is, why `TheGuardian.data_to_csv()` method receives `<class 'script_guardian.TheGuardian'>` instead `<class 'dict'>`?

If I have understood correctly,`TheGuardian.data_to_csv()` just receives an instance of TheGuardian class. It has to do with the type of method I'm using? E.g, abstract, static or class method

Steps:

```
>>> from script_guardian import TheGuardian
>>> tg = TheGuardian('2016-01-01', '2018-01-01')
>>> json_content = tg.search_content('education', 'relevance', 'education')
>>> json_content
<bound method Content.get_content_response of <theguardian.theguardian_content.Content object at 0x7f7bb9764c88>>
>>> type(json_content)
<class 'method'>
```

How can I get search_content's return instead the method itself?

My full code:

```
import requests
from theguardian import theguardian_content
import csv

    class TheGuardian:

        def __init__(self, from_date='2016-01-01', to_date='2018-01-01'):
            self.from_date = from_date
            self.to_date = to_date

        def search_content(self, content='education', page_size=10, order_by='relevance', 
            api_key='test'):

            self.content = content
            self.page_size = page_size
            self.order_by = order_by
            self.api_key = api_key

            # create content
            params = {
                'from-date': self.from_date,
                'to_date': self.to_date,
                'order-by': self.order_by,
                'page-size': self.page_size,
                'q': self.content,
                'api': self.api_key
            }

            # create content
            content = theguardian_content.Content(**params)
            pdb.set_trace()
            json_content = content.get_content_response()

            # actual response
            return json_content

        def data_to_csv(self, json_content):

           self.json_content = json_content

            with open('guardian_data.csv','w') as csv_file:
                writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
                writer.writerow(["webUrl", "webPublicationDate", "webTitle", "sectionName", 
                "apiUrl", "id", "isHosted", "sectionId", "type", "pillarId", "pillarName"])


                for result in json_content['response']['results']:
                    writer.writerow(
                        result["webUrl"],
                        result["webPublicationDate"],
                        result["webTitle"],
                        result["sectionName"],
                        result["apiUrl"],
                        result["id"],
                        result["isHosted"],
                        result["sectionId"],
                        result["type"],
                        result["pillarId"],
                        result["pillarName"]
                    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data_to_csv` is incomplete since you are accessing it as a class method. You should define it as `data_to_csv(self,json_content)` and pass the result of search content to it, like `tg.data_to_csv(tg.search_content())`

Take a good look at this doc page, https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Why I cannot simply run: json_content = tg.search_content('education', 'relevance', 'education') and then tg.data_to_csv(json_content)? Doing so, I get TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You'd have to still make changes in TheGuardian class for data_to_csv. As long as you are using a class method, the first parameter is reserved for a reference to the class object. The doc linked above explains it clearly. If you have defined `data_to_csv to be -> data_to_csv(self,json_content)`

Comment: Even doing so, I'm getting the method itself instead the dict returned by search_content. Looks like I'm not calling search_content in json_content = tg.search_content('education', 'relevance', 'education')

Comment: `>>> type(tg.search_content('education', 'relevance', 'education')) =>

<class 'dict'>`
This is what I get when I ran the code.

Comment: Remove pdb.set_trace from your code, that's causing the issue.

Comment: Is this question solved?. If so can you accept the answer, if that resolved it.